# Problems trying to run tensorflow on single CPU core

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using Tensorflow 1.14 and keras 2.3.1 installed using Anaconda on a 64 bit system with 64 bit python. I can't upgrade to Tensorflow 2 because of depreciated stuff I need for my application. I'm trying to compare Tensorflow when running on different number of cores but it always uses all the cores of my CPU. Here's the code I'm using to try to get it to run on a single core:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={"CPU": 8},
                    inter_op_parallelism_threads=8,
                    intra_op_parallelism_threads=1)

sess = tf.Session(config=config)
with sess:
    with tf.device("/CPU:0"):
        Do Stuff and look at CPU core usage.
```

From everything I can find on the web this should work, I've tried multiple versions of this, but all cores are still used to 100% on my cpu :(

Comment: `tf.device("/CPU:0")` means the first CPU not a single core of the CPU. I cannot help you more unfortunately.

Comment: better use tf 2.x, the 1.x will be unsupported eventually

Comment: I would use tf 2.x if I could, but the problem is that I can't :( I just need to get this done and then I'm not going to use it anymore, so spending time upgrading the code to tf 2 isn't really an option :/

Comment: why not `device_count={"CPU": N...` then remove `with tf.device("/CPU:0"):`

Comment: @datdinhquoc Gives the same results :(